# Aiogram 3.x Считывание сообщения с канала?

Tags: python, aiogram

ранее писал на 2.x сложности в переходе, мне нужно получать сообщения из канала где мой бот админ, я пишу простой скрипт для получения вообще всех сообщений которые могут когда-либо быть отправлены в канал или чат.

```py
@dp.message()
async def forward_messages(message: Message):
    print(message)

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Но в моем случае он просто не видит сообщения

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.channel_message Решил через это
```